# Properties of C′(1/6) groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4124859/c1-6-groups-properties) on Math Stack Exchange about a week ago, but nobody answered.

Let $G = \langle X \mid R\rangle$ be a group presentation, where $R$ \subset $F(X)$ is a set of freely and cyclically reduced words, such as $R$ is symmetrized. Presentation satisfies $C'(\lambda)$ condition $0 < \lambda < 1$ iff for any words $u, v \in R$ their common initial segment $w$ has length
$$
|w| < \lambda |u|
$$

I need to prove the following properties of $C'(1/6)$ groups:

1. If $h^k$ is a defining relation, then $k$ is the order of $h$.
2. All finite subgroups are cyclic.
3. All abelian subgroups are cyclic.

I guess I've proved 1. with Greendlinger's lemma, assuming that the order of $h$ is less than $k$ contradicts the $C'(1/6)$ condition.

But I have no idea how to prove 2.–3.

I'm solving some problems of a combinatorial group theory course, but I can't prove 2.–3. I don't see any instruments except definition, Dehn's algorithm and Greendlinger's lemma. In the second and third, I'm trying to explore structure of finite cyclic subgroup by applying Dehn's algorithm to generator and comparing it to relations using Greendlinger's lemma. It turns out (if I'm right) that square of generator must be a subword of some relation. But I don't see how that helps …. I guess I should consider  arbitrary finite (abelian) group and find generator. I have a hypothesis that generator is the shortest word after applying Dehn's algorithm to all elements of this group, but I can't prove it.

Comment: What is a $C'(1/6)$ group?  What does "$h^k$ equals relation" mean?

Comment: Aren't $C'(1/6)$ groups torsion-free? I'm also not sure what you mean by "$h^k$ equals relation".

Comment: No, as I know. This means that h^k is relation in such group. If we assume the order is n < k we get contradiction with 1/6 condition.

Comment: @YCor There are many $C'(1/6)$ groups with torsion, e.g. any one-relator group $\langle A \mid w^n = 1\rangle$ with $n\geq 6$ and $w$ not a proper power.

Comment: The meaning of"$h^k=1$ is a relation" is not completely clear. Do you mean that it is a defining relation (i.e. one of the relations in the $C'(1/6)$ presentation) or just a relation that holds in the group?

Comment: OK, so the probable meaning is that $h^k$ is one of the relators, and then it indeed follows that $k$ is the order of $h$.

Comment: (1) could also be a slightly strange way to phrase that the only torsion is the "obvious" one. That is, if no relation is a proper power, then the group is torsion-free, which certainly is true for $C'(1/6)$-groups.

Comment: Yes, defining relation.

Comment: @YCor: whether or not torsion is allowed in C’(1/6) groups depends on exactly how you define a piece; there are a couple of different possible conventions. In this case, I think it just means that the relators are powers of a C’(1/6) set of relators.

Comment: @xRay, have you tried looking in Lyndon & Schupp? Many of the standard results about small-cancellation theory are proved there.

Comment: @xRay please clarify by editing, also use quantifiers to avoid lengthy speculation about deciphering a question which is easy to formulate precisely.

Comment: Depending on your definition of a $C'(1/6)$ group (if you allow generators of order two), can't you get finite dihedral subgroups too?

Comment: The standard definition of a $C'(1/6)$ group allows relators of the form $w^k=1$ (because $w$ is not a piece of the word $w^k$), so torsion is permitted. However, you can't get a finite dihedral subgroup: this would involve three relators $r^2$, $s^2$ and $(rs)^m$, which would contradict the small cancellation condition as the first and the third one imply that $r$ is a piece, of length longer than $1/6 \cdot \|r^2\|$.

Comment: I am a little surprised that three people have voted to close for lack of clarity. The first conclusion was initially unclear but it is clear now, and in any case it is properties 2 and 3 that seem more interesting. I have never come across those particular properties of $C'(1/6)$ groups myself, and I would very interested to see a reference or proof.

Comment: Property 3 is a theorem of Grindlinger [Grindlinger, M.
The problem of conjugacy and coincidence with an anticenter in the theory of groups. (Russian) Sibirsk. Mat. Ž. 7 1966, 785–803.]. HIs proof is combinatorial, and does not even use van Kampen diagrams. I do not know any modern references. I imagine that a geometric approach to Property 2 is via asphericity: finite order elements give rise to spherical diagrams, and one can show that they must therefore come from defining relators. Property 3 is about diagrams on a torus, and again one can study the structure of them to prove it.